# Flutter Auto-Renewable Subscription never expires in Sandbox

Tags: ios, dictionary, flutter, sandbox

I'm testing the in_app_purchase plugin for Flutter (https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/in_app_purchase).

I've setup an Auto-Renewable Subscription, and was successfully able to purchase is using my sandbox user account (on an actual device).

The problem is that unlike what is described here (Testing Subscription: https://medium.com/swift-india/auto-renewable-subscriptions-for-ios-3a4068f11acd), the subscription doesn't seem to expire.
I've waited for more than 2 hours, terminated the app, uninstalled and re-installed it - but when I call **queryPastPurchases** I always get 1 or more **PurchaseDetails** object...

How can I get a subscription to expire - so I can further test it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is going to help but did you set the `sandboxTesting` property of your `PurchaseParam` to `true` or `false`?

I am experiencing the same issue but have noticed that the purchase goes through even when I set `sandboxTesting` to `false`, this seems like incorrect behaviour considering that I am using a sandbox tester account. Wonder if that has something to do with it.

Comment: Yes I have (sandboxTesting = true). Since then I've learned a lot about this mechanism: you have to take the purchaseDetails.verificationData.serverVerificationData data and verify it agains Apple's / Google's servers (which is a pain). If you require more details I'll be happy to help

Comment: @user6097845 thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I have attempted to implement the verification of receipts against Apple's servers, but continue to get an unsuccessful status code of 21002. Think it may have to do with the issue you mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57188466/calling-buynonconsumable-method-in-in-app-purchase-plugin-for-flutter-with-sandb) - have you had any success in validating receipts?

Comment: @user6097845 Can you please explain a bit how you handle that issue using serverVerificationData? Thanks in advance