# Calling buyNonConsumable method in in_app_purchase plugin for Flutter with sandbox = true and getting sandbox = false when calling queryPastPurchases

Tags: flutter, in-app-purchase

I'm testing the in_app_purchase plugin for Flutter (https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/in_app_purchase).

I'm calling the **buyNonConsumable** method with **sandboxTesting** = true and **applicationUserName** = 'test'.
But after a successful purchase, when calling the queryPastPurchases, I get different values in QueryPurchaseDetailsResponse.pastPurchases[0].skPaymentTransaction.payment fields...

Is it possible that it's causing the issue mentioned here?
[Flutter Auto-Renewable Subscription never expires in Sandbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57146042/flutter-auto-renewable-subscription-never-expires-in-sandbox)